# Neo4j Browser - Connect Result Nodes

Tags: neo4j

The Neo4j browser that installs with the desktop version has a setting "Connect result nodes" that controls whether the browser show connections between nodes resulting from a query (even if they are not related to the original query context).

"Query" in the browser version that opens in Chrome etc when you connect to an Aura instance does not seem to offer a comparable setting?

Am I missing something?

Tried a query in both, cannot control "Connect result nodes" in "Query"

Comment: Interesting.  I have  a local database. I primarily use Firefox and see the "connect the result nodes" option in both Firefox and Chrome. I rarely use this option because it confounds your querying.

Answer (score 0):

"Connect result nodes" currently doesn't exist in "Query" as it did in Browser. It is likely that it will not be implemented either, at least not in the same way, since it was a confusing function, even if useful in many cases, since the result you get back isn't what you would get if you ran the same query elsewhere.